# How to access the variables which are created in Azure variable group in Mule Configuration(in connector properties) file?

Tags: azure-pipelines, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am trying to access the azure variables in the Mule Flows as a property

I have added the variables in azure pipeline goals but those are not accessing. Couldn't find configuration property value for key ${test.username} from properties provider environment properties provider - within resolver Deployment properties trying to process key test.username

Comment: Please share the pipeline configuration so we understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`${test.username}` like this it means this property is in your properties file.
Check on which environment you deploy and then check the corresponding property file.

If its missing you have to add a value in that property, for example:
`test.username=test`.